# Add only text string to element

Tags: vuejs2

I have a prop with a string and i want only a string into a element.

Template:

```
<input type="text" toggleto>
```

Result:

```
<input type="text" toggleto>
```

Desirable result:

```
<input type="text" bla-bla-bla>
```

Prop:

```
export default {
    props: ['toggleto'], // content => bla-bla-bla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template to:

```
<input type="text" v-bind="{[toggleto]:true}">
```